# Search Array of Strings in Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm using Postgres 9.5 and I have a column `col` with arrays like this

```
["ABC","4"]
["4","5","6"]
["ABC"]
```

How do I search for all arrays that contain `'ABC'`?

I've tried everything - `@>`, `ANY`, etc and looked at 20 questions on SO. 
This is the closest I got but it only returns exact matches.

```
select * from t 
where col = '["ABC"]';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct a single-element array and use the “contains” operator:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE arr @> ARRAY['ABC'];
```

A GIN index can speed up this search.